# Cookies doesnot get deleted using jquery cookie plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I am using jquery.cookie.js from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

please let know if anything im missing or understanding wrongly

```
$.cookie('cartQuantity', 3, { expires: 180 , path : '/' });
alert( $.cookie('cartQuantity') ); //alerts 3
$.cookie('cartQuantity', null);
alert( $.cookie('cartQuantity') );//alerts 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the cookie passing the **same** options that you have used for the creation:

```
$.cookie('cartQuantity', null, { expires: 180 , path : '/' });
```

There's also the `$.removeCookie` method which was very [recently](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/commit/84a7de2014acd71d835f5940ad229a0185b2901f#jquery.cookie.js) added to the plugin (2 months ago), so if you are using a version that supports it, you could use it instead.

Comment: why not use `$.removeCookie`, I have always done it that way? Nvm, didn't see edit.

Comment: @Phil: It was added to the plugin just 2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the cookie incorrectly. According to the [docs](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), this is how you should delete it:

```
$.removeCookie('the_cookie'[, options]);
```

so in your case it would be:

```
$.removeCookie('cartQuantity', { expires: 180 , path : '/' });
```

> you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that
>   were used to set the cookie

You don't actually need to include the expires data when deleting.

Comment: if my cookie was intially set to 30min from current time...and i call my delete cookie (15min after currentime)... how i shd specify expiry time?